# How to create pivots for specific values using showpages in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table. I'm trying to create new pivot tables based on the original one but filtered for specific values.

So far I found this:

```
ThisWorkbook.PivotTables("PivotName").ShowPages PageField:="DATE"
```

Which is awesome because this one line creates pivot tables for all dates that are in the pivot and paste them in a new sheet.

**I want to be able to create only 3 sheets for 3 specific dates.** Any ideas??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't restrict .ShowPages to just show three items. Instead, simply copy the PivotTable three times to three sheets, and set the .CurrentPage property of the Date PivotField to the date you want to show for each of them.

In doubt, record a macro, perform the steps you want to do manually, stop the macro recorder, and use the code it generates as a starting point.